# java Can i create a string that is defined as null in one line?

Tags: java, string, constructor, super

I'd like to pass a String parameter as "null"

However, this is for the super method in a constructor - so i cannot do

```
String s = null;
super(s);
```

I cannot just do

```
super(null)
```

as this will result in an ambiguous method call. I don't want to have an instance variable that is null for this either, that seems inelegant.

Is there a way to create a null String?

NB

```
 new String(null) //does not compile
```

Comment: `super((String)null)`

Comment: @AndrewThompson: that should be an answer (as simple as it might look to you).

Comment: @JBNizet  Ehh.. (shrugs)  I'm a bit late coming back to this.  Now it's been put as an answer by others, it seems redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do this

```
super((String)null);
```

Answer (score 3):

CodeMan posted the correct answer, another solution,
move away from null, and consider initializing with Empty string

```
super("");
```

this would avoid a null check later.

Comment: this is true - there is a null check though, and in case we ever do want to do something with a non-null and empty string i thought i'd stay away from this.

Comment: [this conversation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277965/should-i-set-the-initial-java-string-values-from-null-to) I like the bug with the string concatenating but i also like the fact null doesn't go on the heap (though being efficient in java seems a bit pointless).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the compiler do not know which constructor should be used.

String has various single parameter constructor.

```
 String(String)
 String(char value[])
 String(StringBuffer)
 String(StringReader)
```

When you use `String(null)`, it is unknown which should be used.

Remember when you use a `null` as argument (in a method or constructor), you should **always** forward it with cast to desired type.

`new String((String) null);`