# I can't seem to declare this variable in java

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I have to make a horoscope, and in the process I opted to declare a string then set it equal in an `if` statement.

I get an error on the last line, stating that `s` & `t` are not initialized. Am I missing something really simple? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What day of the month were you born? (number)");
    int d = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Which month were you born? (number)");
    int m = scan.nextInt();

    if (m==3 && d>=21 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Aries");
    else if (m==4 && d<=19 && d>=1)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Aries");
    else if (m==4 && d>=20 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Taurus");
    else if (m==5 && d<=20 && d>=1)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Taurus");
    else if (m==5 && d>=21 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Gemini");
    else if (m==6 && d>=1 && d<=20)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Gemini");
    else if (m==6 && d>=21 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Cancer");
    else if (m==7 && d>=1 && d<=22)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Cancer");
    else if (m==7 && d>=23 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Leo");
    else if (m==8 && d>=1 && d<=22)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Leo");
    else if (m==8 && d>=23 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Virgo");
    else if (m==9 && d>=1 && d<=22)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Virgo");
    else if (m==9 && d>=23 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Libra");
    else if (m==10 && d>=1 && d<=22)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Libra");
    else if (m==10 && d>=23 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Scorpio");
    else if (m==11 && d>=1 && d<=21)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Scorpio");
    else if (m==11 && d>=22 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Sagittarius");
    else if (m==12 && d>=1 && d<=21)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Sagittarius");
    else if (m==12 && d>=22 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Capricorn");
    else if (m==1 && d>=1 && d<=19)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Capricorn");
    else if (m==1 && d>=20 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Aquarius");
    else if (m==2 && d>=1 && d<=18)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Aquarius");
    else if (m==2 && d>=19 && d<=31)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Pisces");
    else if (m==3 && d>=1 && d<=20)
      System.out.println("Your sign is Pisces");
    else
      System.out.println("error");

    String s;

    if (m==1)
      s=("January");
    else if (m==2)
      s=("February");
    else if (m==3)
      s=("March");
    else if (m==4)
      s=("April");
    else if (m==5)
      s=("May");
    else if (m==6)
      s=("June");
    else if (m==7)
      s=("July");
    else if (m==8)
      s=("August");
    else if (m==9)
      s=("September");
    else if (m==10)
      s=("October");
    else if (m==11)
      s=("November");
    else if (m==12)
      s=("December");

     String t;

    if (d==1)
      t=("first");
    else if (d==2)
      t=("second");
    else if (d==3)
      t=("third");
    else if (d==4)
      t=("fourth");
    else if (d==5)
      t=("fifth");
    else if (d==6)
      t=("sixth");
    else if (d==7)
      t=("seventh");
    else if (d==8)
      t=("eighth");
    else if (d==9)
      t=("ninth");
    else if (d==10)
      t=("tenth");
    else if (d==11)
      t=("eleventh");
    else if (d==12)
      t=("twelfth");
    else if (d==13)
      t=("thirteenth");
    else if (d==14)
      t=("fourteenth");
    else if (d==15)
      t=("fifteenth");
    else if (d==16)
      t=("sixteenth");
    else if (d==17)
      t=("seventeenth");
    else if (d==18)
      t=("eighteenth");
    else if (d==19)
      t=("nineteenth");
    else if (d==20)
      t=("twentieth");
    else if (d==21)
      t=("twenty-first");
    else if (d==22)
      t=("twenty-second");
    else if (d==23)
      t=("twenty-third");
    else if (d==24)
      t=("twenty-fourth");
    else if (d==25)
      t=("twenty-fifth");
    else if (d==26)
      t=("twenty-sixth");
    else if (d==27)
      t=("twenty-seventh");
    else if (d==28)
      t=("twenty-eighth");
    else if (d==29)
      t=("twenty-ninth");
    else if (d==30)
      t=("thirtieth");
    else if (d==31)
      t=("thirty-first");

    System.out.println("Your birthday is: " + s + " " + t);

    }
}
```

Comment: What if none of the conditions are true? What will `t` or `s` be then? Post your code *here*, read the error, and get rid of those superfluous parentheses..

Comment: Don't do pastebin!

Comment: Put the code in the question. Someone will clean it up for you if it isn't pretty

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help [...] must include [...] the shortest code necessary to reproduce [the problem] in the question itself. [...] See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Just change lines 65 to `String s = "";` and line 92 to `String t = "";`. Initialization done!

Comment: Code formatting is broken.

Comment: what is the exact message you get? I'd expect a better message to be shown, saying "not always initialized" or something like that (there is an execution path that is that would cause an issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from your long string of `if-elseif` code. Where you have

```
else if (d==31)
    t=("thirty-first");
```

Should be

```
else
    t = ("thirty-first");
```

and similarly for s. Java will always complain if your variables are only initialized within conditional statements, because it is possible that they will never be initialized. You could also initialize them with

```
String s = "";
```

to avoid this.

Comment: Ah, it was the second thing that you mentioned, thanks a bunch!

Comment: and I submitted it without doing what you mentioned first. And wouldn't that not work since I need to output an error message if the number is not a real day?

Comment: So if I input 42 as the day I was born, the program will tell me I was born on the thirty-first?

Answer (score 0):

Without checking the rest of the code I wanted to tell you to try fix what java tells you is wrong, namely initialize s & t: e.g

```
String s = "";
```

Read more about similar stuff here:

- [Should I set the initial java String values from null to ""?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277965/should-i-set-the-initial-java-string-values-from-null-to)
- https://coderanch.com/t/397787/java/Declare-initialize-empty-String

Answer (score 0):

Some general pointers regarding your code:

There is no need for paranthesis around string literals. `("first")` can be replaced with `"first"`.

Long chains of `if-else` are hard to read, and considered bad. A `switch` would be better, but I would actually go for a `Map` to solve the day and month at least.

Your code should be split into methods, with each method responsible for one "thing". Here you at least 4 things: (1) input of day and month, (2) calculation of sign, (3) convertion of numbered month to text, and (4) conversion of numbered day to text.

As an example, here is a method for (3):

```
private String getMonthAsString(final Integer monthAsNumber) {
    return createMonthNumberToMonthStringMap().get(monthAsNumber);
}

private Map<Integer, String> createMonthNumberToMonthStringMap() {
    final Map<Integer, String> monthNumberToMonthString = new HashMap<>();
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(1, "January");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(2, "February");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(3, "March");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(4, "April");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(5, "May");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(6, "June");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(7, "July");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(8, "August");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(9, "September");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(10, "October");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(11, "November");
    monthNumberToMonthString.put(12, "Desember");

    return monthNumberToMonthString;
}
```

If an invalid number (-1, 0, 13, etc) is sent to getMonthAsString it will return `null`. You should in these cases throw an exception, or present the user with an error message detailing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Are you expecting Strings to work like primitives?

```
public static void main(String ... args){
  int myInt; //implicitly initialized to 0
  String myString; //not implicitly initialized; objects don't have default values
  myInt=myInt+1; //works! myInt now is one
  myString=yString+"test"; //compilier error, myString was never initiallized 
}
```

---

Edit, saw the posted code:

Note that the compiler is smart enough to know that there is a way through your code where variables were not initialized:

```
public static void main(String ... args){
  String myString; //not implicitly initialized
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int d = scan.nextInt();
  if(d>100){
    myString="hello big world!";
  }else if(d<10){
    myString="hello little world!";
  }
  System.out.println(myString); //error, the compiler knows that myString is uninitialized in some cases.
}
```

Try something like this instead:

```
public static void main(String ... args){
  String myString; //not implicitly initialized
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int d = scan.nextInt();
  if(d>100){
    myString="hello big world!";
  }else if(d<10){
    myString="hello little world!";
  }else{
    myString="hello world!";
  }
  System.out.println(myString); //works! the compiler knows that there is no way through that if block without myString getting set.
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph in your answer, variables (irrespective of whether they are primitives or object references) are not initialized when they are local variables in a method. They are always initialized when they are fields of an object.