# Could not understand the lines of code here

Tags: java

```
String msg = "This is a test";
int key = 88;    
String encmsg = ""; //What does this empty quotes "" means
for(int i=0; i<msg.length(); i++)
  encmsg = encmsg + (char)(msg.charAt(i)^key); //what does this encmsg + does
```

Why can't I directly store the characters in `encmsg` by using

```
encmsg = (char)(msg.charAt(i)^key);
```

Comment: tried casting it to a String instead of a char? if you don't understand what "" means, you really should pick up a textbook and read the first chapters

Comment: Because `encmsg` cannot be used until initialized. Creating `encmsg` inside the `for` loop will reinitialize the value on every iteration.

Comment: i understand that casting thing what i meant to ask was why encmsg + is needed there

Comment: What part of this are you not understanding, exactly?

Comment: i did not understand the empty quote left in the encmsg during initialization and the encmsg + during storing the characters in encmsg

Comment: @DipeshBC if you cast it to a String, that part is not needed there.

Comment: i tried casting to string it didnot worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code seems to encode a message `msg` to an encoded message `encmsg`.

The way you create the encoded string is like this in pseudo code:

1. Start with an empty `encmsg`
2. For each character `c` in `msg`

   3. Compute the bitwise XOR of `c` and `key`
   4. Convert the result to a character
   5. Add the character to the end of `encmsg`

Step 1 explains why you need to initialise `encmsg`. If you miss out the `""`, then you can't concatenate anything to it in step 5 because it does not have a value.

Now it should be clear why you need the `encmsg +` bit. You are looping through each character of `msg` and encoding each character. Then you append each of these encoded characters to the result to form the complete encoded string. You might understand it better if it were written like this:

```
encmsg += (char)(msg.charAt(i)^key);
```

Since you are concatenating strings in a loop, it would be faster if you used a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
String msg = "This is a test";
int key = 88;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<msg.length(); i++)
    sb.append((char)(msg.charAt(i)^key));
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Depending on the size of `msg` wouldn't it make sense to replace the concatenation with a StringBuilder since it gets invoked anyway? Regarding large messages this would increase performance by a lot.

Comment: @L.Spillner `StringBuilder` would help. But seeing OP having trouble understanding the code without a string builder, I think a string builder would confuse them even more.

Comment: Thank you very much i asked my question the wrong way but you understood the question i meant to ask anyway :)  and can you refer me some good books of programming right now i am reading java a beginners guide

Comment: @DipeshBC I learned programming through Java for Dummies. Anyway, book recommendations is not a question suitable for stack overflow. Also, if my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

For `String encmsg = "";` follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277965/should-i-set-the-initial-java-string-values-from-null-to)

In this line,
`encmsg = encmsg + (char)(msg.charAt(i)^key);//what does this encmsg + does` + is used for concatinating(appending) data to create string.

Also, you cannot replace the above line with this because `encmsg = (char)(msg.charAt(i)^key);` following is used to assigning the value.

whereas the purpose is to appending the data to create string.