# Should I pre-initialize a variable that is overwritten in multiple branches?

Tags: java, string

There is a method:

```
private String myMethod(String gender)
{
    String newString = "";
    if(gender.equals("a"))
        newString = internal.getValue();
    else
        newString = external.getValue();

    return newString;
}
```

I refactored everything, but with one small change:
`String newString;` instead of: `String newString = "";`

Does this refactor improve the code? I know that `String` is `null` when we don't initialize it, but in this example it always will have value a from `if` or `else`. Does this refactor change anything?

Comment: Returning two times here would be the more readable solution. Your code sample is missing the return by the way. Furthermore the initial assignment is confusing as it's value is never used and always overiden. This one is about clarity of intent and the initial assignment makes the overall code more unclear

Comment: In both branches you give it a value, so there's no point in giving it an "initial" value one line earlier.  You could replace the whole thing with `String newString = gender.equals("a") ? internal.getValue() : external.getValue();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I set the initial java String values from null to ""?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277965/should-i-set-the-initial-java-string-values-from-null-to)

Comment: Uninitialized *local* variables are *not* null; they have no observable value at all.

Comment: Also note that Java 7 onwards allow using Strings in switch statements.  For more complex code than this, that may be very useful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer the direct question: there's no need to assign a value initially here; all branches of the code's execution will pan out to giving `newString` a value. Thus you don't need to initialize it at all. Otherwise, I would initialize to whatever you would want as a "default" value.

Instead of two returns or a branching statement to assign a variable, I would just return with a ternary:

```
private String myMethod(String gender) {
    return gender.equals("a")
            ? internal.getValue()
            : external.getValue();
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the conditional operator is not a semantic replacement for if/else. It's not important here, but, say, `Number foo(boolean c) { if (c) return Integer.valueOf(0); else return Double.valueOf(0); }` isn't the same as `return c ? Integer.valueOf(0) : Double.valueOf(0);`, because the latter always results in a `Double`.

Comment: Yes, but in this case they're `Strings`, and I wouldn't really suggest returning such an abstract type with behavior that differentiates around double vs int. In fact by using `Number` you're restricting yourself to `#intValue` etc/casting before you can use the number in a meaningful way anyhow (no math operators). The ternary will type to the most specific supertype bound, which is relevant, but I just think the number example in specific here is a bad idea anyhow.

Comment: you might not suggest it, but I can assure you that it happens (I wrote [the check banning it in Google's codebase](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ConditionalExpressionNumericPromotion), which also turned up an instance in the JDK).

Comment: Oh for sure, people will do it. I moreso meant it seems like a serious flaw to attempt a design around having a double _or_ integer return (even if functional) for some method. Also, fan of error-prone.

Answer (score 18):

> Is it better to initialize String or to leave it as null?

Your premise is flawed: not initializing the String doesn't mean its value is null.

You are not allowed to use a local variable before it has been assigned, in order to avoid you accidentally using a value you didn't intend. As such, the value isn't "null", it's undefined (*).

This is called [*definite assignment* checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_assignment_analysis), and is there to prevent certain types of bug. If you give the variable a value you don't need to give it, you disable this check, and so are open to the bugs the compiler was trying to protect you from.

For example, if the code looked like this:

```
private String myMethod(String gender)
{
    String newString = "";
    if(gender.equals("a"))
        newString = internal.getValue();
    else if (gender.equals("b");
        newString = external.getValue();
    // Oops! meant to check if gender.equals("c")

    return newString;
}
```

you might have a bug, because there is a missing case that you haven't checked.

If you had explicitly assigned `null` to the variable, you would have much the same issue; but now your method would return null, and so possibly cause an NPE in the calling code.

If you had omitted the `= ""`, the compiler would stop you using `newString` in the return.

(Assigning and reassigning the variable also means the variable would not be effectively final, so you would be unable to use it inside a lambda or anonymous class).

---

(*) This only applies to local variables, and `final` member/static variables. Class members do not have to be definitely assigned before use if they are not final, which is a rich seam for bugs, and a good reason to make class members final wherever possible. And, technically, `final` members are initialized to their type's default value first, so you can actually read them as `null` before they are initialized.

Comment: +1 I think this answer best answers the question `Does this refactor improve the code?` that OP asked because it discusses `definite assignment checking`.

Answer (score 9):

It's best to only initialize a `String` (or anything else) if there is a scenario in which the initial value is used.

In your case you have assigned `newString` to a string literal that serves no purpose but to confuse the reader.

It should be evident that the performance and functionality will not change in any relavent way.

Answer (score 3):

My take on the shortest form without the terniary operator (which I think decreases readability) :

```
private String myMethod(String gender)
{
    if(gender.equals("a"))
        return internal.getValue();
    return external.getValue();
}
```

I would probably have a full `if {...} else {...}` construct like the other answers in my own code.

Also not all debuggers can easily show what is being returned from a method as part of the normal flow, so it may be easier if the return value is captured in a variable and THEN returned (where the breakpoint can be put on the return statement)

Comment: Do you think `"a".equals(gender)` is better since it can handle `null`?

Comment: @KorayTugay only if you expect that `gender` can be null. Otherwise, this just hides the bug resulting in `gender` being unexpectedly null.

Comment: @KorayTugay Doing this subtly changes the behavior of the code so it is _not_ a proper refactoring.  This is perhaps some of the most dangerous drive-by "fixing" as there may be calling code relying on this behavior (but hopefully not) which you will then subtly break.   The best way to handle this is either to document that null is expected in the javadoc (perhaps even annotating with a null-is-allowed annotation) or to introduce an explicit check that gender is not null.  (Options.requireNotNull is well suited for this)

Answer (score 2):

You can make this string `final` and keep unassigned to be sure that all `if` branches assigns the value:

```java
final String result;
if (condition1) {
    result = "one";
} else if (condition2) {
    result = "two";
} else {
    result = "other";
}
return result;
```

With this approach compiler will check that `result` variable was assigned once in each branch. It may be helpful if you add one more condition branch, or if you try to overwrite variable by mistake - compiler will fail and show the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your case (if else condition) there no need to initialize the `String`, you can simple put it as `String newString;` and that would be ok because either way, at the end it will have a different value.

```
private String myMethod(String gender)
{
    String newString;

    if(gender.equals("a"))
        newString = internal.getValue();
    else
        newString = external.getValue();

    // Missing return statement.
}
```

Also, I see that you have a function that returns a string. Assuming that the `newString` variable is what you will be returning, instead of creating a string variable you can simple return the string in the condition:

```
private String myMethod(String gender)
{
    if(gender.equals("a"))
        return internal.getValue();
    else
        return external.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My colleges are right, this can be done with the tenary operator.
In addition I thinks its very important to prevent NullPoiterExeptions as often as possible.
What if gender would be null? NullPointerException
I would switch "a" and gender like this:

```
    private String myMethod(String gender) {
        return "a".equals(gender)
            ? internal.getValue()
            : external.getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> ### Default Values
>
> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.
>
> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.